# How to show one row if it has more rows in inner join and left join query?

Tags: php

I have more than one shop  in `ps_shop` table  and its some of shop have in `ps_storeinfo` table  but those shop of `ps_shop` table  are not in `ps_storeinfo` table  that are needed to insert into `ps_storeinfo` with user id and shop name. Here  shopname  of  `ps_shop` table  =  storename in  `ps_storeinfo`  table. Here I have written sql query for this and I am getting all data but problem is more than one user is coming by my SQL if it have more than one user. I need one user for one shop.

In `ps_ employee_shop` table user is assigned for shop base on shop id.  And In `ps_ employee` table is for user.  This is for prestashop 1.6.

My SQL is given below :

```
$table_prefix = _DB_PREFIX_; 

'SELECT ps.*, pe.email, pe.firstname, pe.lastname, pes.id_employee,psi.storename 
        FROM '.$table_prefix.'shop ps 
        LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'storeinfo psi  ON ps.name = psi.storename 
        INNER JOIN '.$table_prefix.'employee_shop pes ON ps.id_shop = pes.id_shop
        INNER JOIN '.$table_prefix.'employee pe ON pes.id_employee = pe.id_employee where ps.id_shop <>1 and pe.id_employee <>1
         GROUP BY pes.id_employee 
        ';
```

Output image is:

[image]

Comment: just add `group by shop's primary key` and it should work

Comment: Thank u. Your suggestion is working.

Comment: I have corrected the formatting of this question with this edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if more than one entity exists in the table on the right side of the `JOIN` with the matching `ON` key any relational DB engine will return one row for each matching entity on the right side, duplicating the left side of the `JOIN` clause.

In the scenario described you need to decide which user you want to return. The first one sorted alphabetically? The one created most recently?

Based on the answer you will need to use a JOIN with a correlated subquery. Here's an example for getting the employee with the highest value of `id_employee`:

```
SELECT
    ps.*, pe.email, pe.firstname, pe.lastname, pes.id_employee,psi.storename
FROM
    '.$table_prefix.'shop ps
    LEFT JOIN '.$table_prefix.'storeinfo psi ON ps.name = psi.storename 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            pe.email, pe.firstname, pe.lastname, pes.id_employee
        FROM
            '.$table_prefix.'employee pe
            '.$table_prefix.'employee_shop pes ON pes.id_employee = pe.id_employee
        WHERE
            pe.id_employee <> 1
            AND ps.id_shop = pes.id_shop
        ORDER BY
            pe.id_employee DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE
    ps.id_shop <>1
```

As you can see what this is really doing is limiting the resulting list of employees to just one record to avoid duplication. In this case the list is ordered by id_employee, but the correct ordering depends on the business logic that needs to be implemented.